# Need to delay the checkbox order

Tags: javascript, sorting, checkbox, timer, delay

I need to make this checkbox script delay for 1-2 secound before it change the order of the checked items and the way around.

```
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Two</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="four" />Four</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label></li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
var list = $("ul"),
    origOrder = list.children();

list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
    var i, checked = document.createDocumentFragment(),
        unchecked = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
        if (origOrder[i].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].checked) {
            checked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        } else {
            unchecked.appendChild(origOrder[i]);
        }
    }
    list.append(checked).append(unchecked);
});
```

Have tried to put a timer on, but failed...

Comment: What do you mean when you say you tried a timer but it failed?  How did you add it?  In what way did it fail?

Comment: Provide the code of your attempt with *a timer*.

Comment: Why? I mean, if you need to animate the stuff, go check css!

Comment: Why the mix of jQuery and pure DOM methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly certain what expected result is, though you can `.prependTo()`, `.append()`, `setTimeout()`

```js
var list = $("ul"),
    origOrder = list.find("li"),
    duration = 1000,
    timeout = null;

list.on("click", ":checkbox", function() {
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    var i, checked = [],
        unchecked = [];
    for (i = 0; i < origOrder.length; i++) {
        if (origOrder.eq(i).find(":checked").length) {
            checked.push(origOrder[i]);
        } else {
            unchecked.push(origOrder[i]);
        }
    }
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $(checked).prependTo(list);
        list.append(unchecked);
      }, duration)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Two</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="four" />Four</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is not to disappear. But the checked item must wait 1 - 2sec before it moves to the top. When running an FadeIn function when it disappears and when it comes back at the top :)

Comment: Thanks alot! Exactly what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with some fade animation of the moving item. I also changed some code to use jQuery instead of DOM methods

```js
$(function () {
    var $list = $('ul');
    var $items = $list.children();
    var timer = -1;

    function reorder() {
        $items.each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:checked').length) {
                $list.append($(this));
            }
        });
        $items.each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('input:checkbox:not(:checked)').length) {
                $list.append($(this));
            }
        });
    }
    
    $list.on("click", ":checkbox", function () {
        var $item = $(this).closest('li');
        clearTimeout(timer); // cancel previous timeout
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            // fade out clicked item
            $item.fadeOut(400, function () {
                // when faded out, reorder the items
                reorder();
                // fade in clicked item at its new position
                $item.fadeIn(400);
            });
        }, 500);
    });
    
    // At page load, also reorder, as some browsers retain previous checkmarks
    reorder();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="one" />One</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="two" />Two</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="three" />Three</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="four" />Four</label></li>
<li><label><input type="checkbox" id="five" />Five</label></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey @trincot it actually works very well. thanks!
I tried to change `append` to `prepend` so it would put items at the bottom instead of the top and  it worked, but it turns the list upside down.

Comment: You want the checked items at the bottom? In that case swap the two `$items.each` parts in the `reorder` function, and keep using `append`.